# CSS: Compass Susy Grid is not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, susy-compass, compass-sass

im trying to get susy correctly working within compass.

Look at the following html sample (body part):

```
<div class='page'>
  <header class='header border'>
    <nav class='nav border'>
      <ul>
        <li>Nav1</li>
        <li>Nav2</li>
        <li>Nav3</li>
        <li>Nav4</li>
        <li>Nav5</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class='test border'>TEST</section>
  </header>
  <section class='section border'>Section 1</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 2</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 3</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 4</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 5</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 6</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 7</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 8</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 9</section>
  <section class='section border'>Section 10</section>
  <footer class='footer border'>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

... and the according sass code:

```
@import "compass"
@import "susy"

$total-columns : 6
$column-width  : 4em
$gutter-width  : 1em
$grid-padding  : $gutter-width

.page
    +container($total-columns)
    +susy-grid-background

.header
    +span-columns($total-columns)

.nav
    +span-columns($total-columns)

.test
    +span-columns($total-columns)

.footer
    +span-columns($total-columns)

.section
    +span-columns(3)
    &:last-child
        +span-columns(3 omega)

.border
    border: 1px solid black
```

2 "Section X" items should be on one line here (span-columns is set to 3, and 3 + 3 is the number of $total-columns?), but it looks like this (only stacked):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb7og.png

Removing the test-borders also doesnt work. What im doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't there be semicolons after the @import lines?

Comment: not needed, because its the sass syntax, not scss (look at http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html#id26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Unless you are using the `border-box` model, you do need to remove those borders. Try using `outline` for testing instead - as it doesn't affect the flow:

   ```
   .border
     outline: 1px solid black
   ```
2. None of your sections actually match the `.section:last-child` selector. None of them are the last child of their parent element, and so none are getting the `omega` mixin added to them. First, you either need to wrap them so `-child` selectors work, or use `-of-type`. Then you need to use `nth-` instead of `last-`, because you don't just want to match the final one, you want to match all the *even* ones:

   ```
   // without changing your markup
   .section
     +span-columns(3)
     &:nth-of-type(even)
       +omega

   // with a new wrapper around your sections
   .section
     +span-columns(3)
     &:nth-child(even)
       +omega
   ```